# LibreOffice not opening

Tags: libreoffice

If a try to open LibreOffice or any document (spreadsheets, presentations, written or .doc files), it will atempt to start the aplication and just exit it with no error before starting.

Comment: try running it from command line. maybe it will prompt some message

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but only with Writer (Calc works fine). Answers below don't fix it, terminal outputs nothing.

Answer (score 3):

From a terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd>):

Create a folder called `user` in `~/.config/libreoffice/3/`.

Then, copy files from `/usr/lib/libreoffice/share` to
`~/.config/libreoffice/3/user/`

Finally, change owner group and permissions, then run libreoffice.

Answer (score 2):

Open up a terminal and run the following command:

```
libreoffice --writer
```

That way you will get output from the start in your terminal and most likely an error message that gives at least a hint. If you don't see what the problem is right away post the output here.

For other terminal options try "libreoffice --help".

Comment: Hi, I know this is an old thread, but I have tried this and I get no error message. The terminal simply moves to a new line when trying to open a .docx file.