# After LibreOffice updated it won't start!

Tags: updates, libreoffice, partial-upgrade

I read Seth's post here: [How do I install LibreOffice 4?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252612/how-do-i-install-libreoffice-4/252613#252613). I wanted to upgrade, so I ran the commands as provided by Mik to upgrade using stable ppa.
 For some reason now when I try to run LibreOffice it starts up, shows the splash screen, loads about maybe 2-3% and then quits, giving me an Ubuntu error. I might have only partially updated/upgraded, so this might be part of the problem...I'm not sure.

HELP!! I really need to use LibreOffice for a Biology class I have. I can use Abiword for now, but I really prefer LibreOffice.

I want to try and fix it, but if I don't get a quick answer I am afraid I may have to go to (Heaven forbid) Windows XP I dual-boot with to use MS Word/Open Office.

**Here's the error output I got when I launched writer from terminal:**

```
nate@texno-Satellite-A105:~$ libreoffice --writer
javaldx: Could not find a Java Runtime Environment!
Warning: failed to read path from javaldx

terminate called after throwing an instance of com::sun::star::uno::DeploymentException'
```

Comment: What is the actual error? Please put it in your question.

Comment: It's not doing it now, it just quits, no error :( It was giving me the error prior to the reboot I did.

Comment: Boot it from terminal?

Comment: Ok, I will try starting it from terminal. Done!

Comment: Is this a fix? http://askubuntu.com/questions/129383/libreoffice-not-opening

Comment: If you suspect it's a problem during installation, try `sudo apt-get install -f` to fix it.

Comment: yeah. That worked great! I backed up that directory, so should I try restoring certain files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case the solution centered around my suggestion that files in `~/.config/libreoffice` were causing the problems after the upgrade.

**Important Note**: you may want to make a copy of your libreoffice folder if it has any important custom files in it before you remove it.

If the permissions are correct and `libreoffice` still doesn't launch, then delete `~/.config/libreoffice` in your filebrowser or with

```
rm -rf ~/.config/libreoffice
```

and `libreoffice` will regenerate a new folder when it starts.

---

If, for future readers, the suggestions made so far are unsuccessful, you could install `ppa-purge` with

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

and downgrade all the libreoffice packages by entering

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-4-0
```

and then reinstall the standard repository version of `libreoffice`.